# Is it possible to use OUnit in Ocaide?

Tags: ocaml, ounit

I'm trying to use Ocaide in Eclipse, and need to use OUnit.  All the instructions I find are for using it at the command line.  I tried to edit the run configurations by adding `-pkgs oUnit` but that didn't work.  I found instructions elsewhere that had the flags and arguments `-package oUnit -linkpkg -g` so I tried putting that in, but still the IDE doesn't recognize the existence of OUnit.

My file merely has

```
open OUnit2;;
```

and nothing else.  The compiler throws an error saying that the module is unbound.

I have OCaml and OUnit both installed through OPAM, running on Linux Mint.

Comment: Have you checked whether everything works fine on the command line (i.e. `ocamlfind ocamlc -package oUnit -linkpkg -g file.ml` in a terminal succeeds)?

Comment: @Virgile Yep, you nailed.  I didn't realize that I had installed OUnit on one computer and not this one.  After installing, then adding `-package oUnit -linkpkg -g` to the module command arguments worked.